# Center a div in a circle

Tags: html, css

I have a circle in which I can't center the div with text.
I tried with flexbox but it doesn't seem to work or I did it wrong.

This is the code

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 2s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  background-color: #14b1e7;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.words {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: forwards;
  animation-direction: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="words"></div>
  <div class="words1"></div>
  <div class="words2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `display:flex`, `align-items:center` and `justify-content:center`

```css
.circle{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #14b1e7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem comes from `padding-top: 100%;` on your `.circle`. You're using this to get a height on your `.circle`, but it is essentially pushing all of the nested div's content to the bottom. Instead, set a `height` on your `html, body` and use `height: 100%;` on your `.circle`. Then you can set `display: flex;` with `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;` on the parent.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 2s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  background-color: #14b1e7;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.words {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: forwards;
  animation-direction: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="words">foo</div>
  <div class="words1">foo</div>
  <div class="words2">foo</div>
</div>
```